# How do I automatically update fields on a custom object with information from Events?

Tags: custom-object, process-builder, calendar, junction-object

and thank you all for taking the time to read my question!

Here's what we're trying to accomplish:

Automatically populate a "parent" object, Project, with information from an Event used to schedule our field techs. (Specifically, the information needed is "Field Tech", "Start Date", and "End Date".) This would enable us to view our event information easily and "natively" inside the Project record. With the extension of Calendar abilities in Lightning, namely viewing standard and custom objects on a calendar, I'm open to doing this through a custom object that emulates Events.

Challenges:

Cannot trigger a Process Builder process upon record deletion
Multiple Events (of any type) can be associated with a Project
Once a corresponding field on Project is modified, I don't know how to update that field when the Event (or custom object) is modified

Things I've tried:

Creating a junction object connecting Project and event-like custom object
Running multiple processes invoked on the different objects and processes

To reiterate, in a nutshell, I want the ability for our admin to create an Event or event-like custom object and have this information dynamically populated into the Project object.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for all the great posts and responses here!

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup field from Event(custom obj) to Project  and update those fields with an APEX trigger

Comment: Friendly reminder that best practice is not to put business logic in Apex Triggers.  Apex Triggers should govern execution but the actual DML statements should be done within Apex Classes that your Trigger calls into.